# QT code, nothing happens when I run the program

Tags: python, qt, class, user-interface, pycharm

I am learning qt at the moment and I have an issue of comprehending why my code does not work as I want it to. 
It simply does not output anything. No window showing up, the test print statements are not even shown, just nothingness

The awkward thing is, the code returns the exit code 0, there are no obvious problems in PyCharm to be seen and I am lost. I consulted a couple of friends, but neither one of them was able to help me out with this.

```
from PySide.QtGui import QWidget, QApplication, QCheckBox, QPushButton, QPixmap, QLabel, QRadioButton
import sys

class ersteklasse(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ersteklasse, self).__init__()
        self.initGui()
        self.initButton()

        print "I am there"

    def initGui(self):
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 800, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle('Henris kleines Programm')
        filepath = '/Users/henrinehlsen/Desktop/KaNe_Logo_TEST_PORTFOLIOBOX.png'
        pix1 = QPixmap(filepath)
        self.img1 = QLabel
        self.img1.setPixmap(pix1)

        print "me too!"

    def initButton(self):
        self.Button1 = QRadioButton("Nope", self)
        self.Button1.move(100, 100)

if __name__ == "main":
    app = QApplication
    ErstesProgramm = ersteklasse()
    ErstesProgramm.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Don't "fix" your question so it's no longer a *question* - it would invalidate the entire purpose of Stack Overflow as a site for "Questions and Answers". As a new member, you should read the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

```
if __name__ == "main":
```

should read

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

Comment: Did this fix your problem? If not: comment here, or ask a new question. If so: could you accept this, so that future readers know it did the trick?